# Fingerprint after inactivity

Tags: android, security, authentication, authorization, fingerprint

I am implementing fingerprint support to protect sensitive areas of my app and access to some web APIs (using a signature).  I am initializing the key generator like this:

```
            keyPairGenerator.initialize(
                KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder(KEY_NAME, KeyProperties.PURPOSE_SIGN)
                .setDigests(KeyProperties.DIGEST_SHA256)
                .setAlgorithmParameterSpec(ECGenParameterSpec("secp256r1"))
                .setUserAuthenticationRequired(true)
                .setInvalidatedByBiometricEnrollment(true)
                .build()
        )
```

This setup will require the user's fingerprint every time the key is retrieved to create the signature.  The behavior I want is more like this:

```
            keyPairGenerator.initialize(
                KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder(KEY_NAME, KeyProperties.PURPOSE_SIGN)
                .setDigests(KeyProperties.DIGEST_SHA256)
                .setAlgorithmParameterSpec(ECGenParameterSpec("secp256r1"))
                .setUserAuthenticationRequired(true)
                .setUserAuthenticationValidityDurationSeconds(10)
                .setInvalidatedByBiometricEnrollment(true)
                .build()
        )
```

Here the authenticaation is good for 10 seconds because of "setUserAuthenticationValidityDurationSeconds".  What I really want is something like "setUserAuthenticationInvalidAfterInactivitySeconds".  In other words I would like the authentication to be invalidated only after a period of user inactivity in my app.  Does this exist or do I have to create something proprietary?

Comment: If you mean that you want some sort of callback when the last authentication expires, then no, you won't get that, so you'll have to implement that yourself.

Comment: I'm not really looking for a callback.  If the user is active in the application, I don't want them to have to authenticate again to use the key.  Using a CryptoObject forces you to either authenticate each time or every N seconds.  This just doesn't work for my use case.